# SSIS Errorcode -1073450952

Tags: sql-server, ssis

We're executing a SSIS package from a Quartz-Job.
Normally, all works well but today suddenly and without changing anything, following error occurred:

> Exception occurred in job 'BackupJob'; Exception type: OurException; Exception message: Error occurred in data copier. Source='Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.TaskHost' ErrorCode='-1073450952' SubComponent='SSIS.Pipeline' TypeDescription='SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PRIMEOUTPUTFAILED.  The PrimeOutput method on Bst Person 1 returned error code 0xC02020C4.  The component returned a failure code when the pipeline engine called PrimeOutput(). The meaning of the failure code is defined by the component, but the error is fatal and the pipeline stopped executing.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.
>   ' HelpFile='dtsmsg110.rll' HelpContext='0' IdofInterfaceWithError='{B6F6D221-FC27-4F71-B5A0-597583986C28}' 
>   StackTrace:

I have no idea what this means and couldn't find anything on the internet on how to fix it.
I've tried to restart the job 5 times now but every time this error happens...

Have you ever encountered this problem and know how to fix it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the RAM size on machine where SQL Server is running and how much of it is free when this job is running?

Answer (score 0):

Usually when something like this happened I looked at several things:

- is there enough space on the disk for backups ?
- is everything alright with the security ? (I've seen cases where the machine couldn't connect to the AD directory and because of that the authentication failed at the scheduled time). 
  Most of the times if I just rerun the job then it will work (because it can connect to the AD machine)

If this doesn't work I recommend trying to run the job in SSIS (Visual Studio debug mode). Maybe you get a more descriptive error message.